# Two external DELL monitors with DELL laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dell

I have DELL laptop and two externals DELL monitors. I want to plug them and have two screens (laptop will be closed).
I did try to plug them into dock station with:

- two DiplayPort cables
- one DisplayPort and one HDMI

That didn't work. Always only one of the external monitors are on. I can turn on one external monitor and laptop display but can't get to work two external monitors simultaneously.
When I log in every 3 monitors are violet so laptop can see all of them in a way.

[EDIT]
I just discovered that it works when both monitors are 2048x1080 resolution. It do not work when both are 2560x1440.
So the question is, can I use them both in higher resolution?

neofetch:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64 
Host: Latitude 5510 
Kernel: 5.13.0-37-generic 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 2560x1440 
DE: GNOME 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-10810U (12) @ 4.900GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon 540X/550X/630 / RX 640 / E9171 MCM 
GPU: Intel Device 9bca 
Memory: 4552MiB / 15603MiB
```

Xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.97    59.96    59.93    48.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1440     59.95 +
   1920x1200     59.88  
   2048x1080     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1200     59.88  
   2048x1080     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Monitors.xml

Comment: Hello. Are you sure of the way the docking station uses the monitors? Does it support what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I just discovered that it works when both monitors are 2048x1080 resolution. It do not work when both are 2560x1440. I did edit my question.

Comment: Seems like you have solved the problem. Use that setting. You may want to contact the people that make the dock and ask them.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So this post can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the resolution max with 2 monitors is 2048x1080. With out confirming something different with the maker of the docking station this is the answer. Use that resolution. Or use a single monitor with the higher resolution. You need to decide what is best for you.